# How to sort Django's list_display of a function using admin_order_field?

Tags: python, django

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def got_inactive_variation(self, obj):
        res = obj.active_variation.__func__(obj)
        var_list = [i for i in res]
        active_list = []
        for i in var_list:
            active_list.append(i.is_active)
        if False in active_list:
            return 'Yes'
        else:
            return 'No'
    got_inactive_variation.admin_order_field = "???"
    got_inactive_variation.short_description = 'Got Inactive Variation'
    list_display = (
        'product_name', 'product_description', 'price', 'stock', 'is_available', 'category',
        'created_date', 'sku', 'got_inactive_variation')
```

As the code above, I want to be able to sort the got_inactive_variation, but what should I put in the right side of admin_order_field?

Comment: Why don't you simply mention it in `Meta` class inside models?

Comment: obj.active_variation.__func__(obj) is a bind function of  a function in Product model that queries a foreign key field from the Variation model.  In admin.py I once again use got_inactive_variation method to get results of bind function by doing __func__(obj).  Can't do Meta class because what I'm trying to get is not a field of a Product model but a foreign key field of Variation model.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but the obj.active_variation.__func__(obj) is calling the method of  def active_variation(self):
        variation_obj = Variation.objects.filter(product=self)
        return variation_obj.  This method resides under Product model.  ProductAdmin in admin.py is calling it, then returns results in list_display.  What do you mean doing it a meta class?  Product's model doesn't have a foreign key field for Variation's is_active field.  Instead, Product is a parent of Variation model.  In Variation model it got product as a foreign key field.